# Populating a List View with file names from OpenFileDialog using VB

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2012, rows, openfiledialog

I am trying to use a List View to show the files a user has selected for processing.

So far I've got:

```
If fd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    posFilename = fd.FileName
    For Each posfilename As String In fd.FileNames
        ListView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(posfilename))
    Next
End If
```

I would like each file name to be on a separate row, but the result gives me file names in separate columns instead.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You've got the View property set wrong.  If you want rows then you need View = Details.  And add a ColumnHeader to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the symptom you are describing, it sounds like you're ListView1 is actually a ListViewItem and you're adding columns.  When I created a sample app with a listview and a OpenFileDialog, it worked as expected.

Just to be clear, your listview IS set into Details View, right?

Comment: Derp, that was it. Thanks guys.